# Detecting Ruby on Rails boot context for a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

Is it possible to detect under which context a Ruby gem is being loaded in Ruby on Rails?

e.g. Is the current process a Rake task being run, a Rails console or an actual server process?

...since in most cases, the full environment is loaded for each of those scenarios

Comment: You could look at `$0` and try and determine what's going on.

Comment: Excellent point.  It's always the simple things that get overlooked... :)  You should add this as an answer so I can select.  Thanks.